# use an interface on a function created with javascript function literal syntax

Tags: typescript

In JavaScript, we can create a function using two ways:

1.

```js
function X(){
}
```

2. 

```js
const x = function(){
}
```

Using typescript, we can for example do the following:

```
interface LogFunction {
  (sources: any[]): void
}
const log: LogFunction = (...sources) => {
  // ...
}
```

We can type the function using an interface, then we can assign it to the variable log.

Can we do the same for function definitions? I mean functions which are created separately, not assigned to variables, ex:

```
function log: LogFunction(...sources) {
 // ...
}
```

Comment: No, there is a longstanding open feature request for this at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22063